# Opening an external notebook with DSX Desktop

Tags: data-science-experience, dsx-desktop

I have an IPython notebook on a directory in my Desktop. This directory also contains supporting Python (.py) files that the notebook imports.

How can I open the notebook with **DSX Desktop** **without moving everything to the 'mynotebooks' directory**? (/Users/username/Library/Application Support/ibm-dsx-desktop/Notebooks/mynotebooks in mac, source: https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/desktop/files.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

#### To import your notebook

1. Go inside a project
2. Click the "+" icon in the top-right corner and choose "Create notebook"
3. Select "From File" and choose the notebook to import

#### To upload your supporting python files (and assets in general)

1. Go inside a project or have a notebook open
2. Click the "+" icon in the top-right corner and choose "Add data set"
3. Choose the assets to upload (your python files)

[image: import assets]

#### Accessing your assets from inside a notebook

You can access your assets from inside a notebook via the path `../datasets/<asset name>`. Jupyter provides code completion which is helpful.

[image: use asset]